# Confusion about theme's parent and child functions.php file

Tags: theme-development, themes, child-theme

So I read WordPress documentation here:
https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/theme-functions/

Where there's such statement:

> Although the child theme’s functions.php is loaded by WordPress right
> before the parent theme’s functions.php, it does not override it. The
> child theme’s functions.php can be used to augment or replace the
> parent theme’s functions. Similarly, functions.php is loaded after any
> plugin files have loaded.

I'm confused about the first sentence there, it says that child theme's functions.php is loaded right before the parent theme's functions.php. And it says, it does not override it.

So according to this, the order in which files are loaded are as follows:

1. Child Theme's functions.php is loaded
2. Parent Theme's functions.php is loaded

Then stating that 'it does not override it'. Does it mean child does not override parent, or parent does not override child? Of course thinking in terms of OOP, and inheritance it makes sense to think that things inplemented in child's file would override parent's stuff.

Meanwhile, I made an experiment, installed a fresh copy of WordPress (as of the date of the post), created parent's theme called 'my-theme' with three files: index.php, style.css, functions.php, then created child theme, with basically everything the same just different folder name 'my-theme-child'. Activated child theme, wrote a line in child's functions.php:

```
<?php
echo "FROM CHILD";
```

Then also added this (in parent's theme functions.php file):

```
<?php
    echo "FROM PARENT";
```

And what I found is only "FROM CHILD" 'echo' statement was executed, so I thought if child's functions.php does not override, parent's functions.php, then surely parent's functions.php should be executed, I wanted to confirm, test the order of execution, and as I said turned out only child's functions.php was executed, so to me it feels like a misunderstanding, lastly it also states you can augment or replace parent's theme functions, but how can you really augment something if it does not exist, meanwhile stating that you can replace parent's functions in my case is correct, since parent's functions, or other statements were not executed in the first place so I get it that I can effectively use the same function names in my child's functions.php file which were used in parent functions.php.

It confused me quite a bit, as I'm confused myself whether what is written not truth, or I misunderstand the meaning of it, as my English is not native language, it happens rarely where I completely misunderstand such things.

So to make my questions more brief:

- In what sense it does not override parent's functions.php?
- Is it    wrong to think that first child should have been executed
  and then    code inside parent's functions.php?

Comment: Both functions.php load. If you did not see both echo statements, something is wrong with your Child Theme configuration. It very much works like a PHP include statement, first, the child theme functions.php is included, then the parents functions.php is included.